# How to copy a .txt file into your projects directory? Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, fstream, ifstream

I have a file named random.txt on my desktop but for some reason VS wont open it, i think it has to do with the directory but idk. is there something wrong with this code? How do I make it read the file?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream infile;
int num, count = 1, total = 0, avg;

infile.open("Random.txt");
if (infile)
    while (infile >> num)
    {
        cout << num << endl;

    }
else
    cout << "The file did not open" << endl;

infile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect your code to magically know that `Random.txt` is located far away in the desktop folder, a long way away from your executable? Would you expect addressing a letter `123 Main Street` to know that you mean the one in Los Angeles, CA when you mail it from Miami, FL without including a city and state?

Comment: ok, well how do I make it read the file then?

Comment: Include the directory with the filename, of course. Or copy the file (using Windows Explorer) into the same folder as your executable. (For future reference, Visual Studio is not a programming language; the language you're writing your code in is C++, and you should be using that tag instead of VS. VS is the IDE where you type your code, build your application. C++ is the language you write code in. They're not the same thing.)

Answer (score 0):

What @Ken White said is completely right. Just for clarification - you have three possible solutions:

**1 - Change file path**

```
infile.open("C:\User\walshline\Desktop\Random.txt");
```

Change the path that it matches your Desktop location. This has the HUGE disadvantage that you can't deploy your software to another computer because the path will be different.

**2 - Ask user for file path**

On startup, you can ask your user for the correct file path.

```
std::string path;
std::cout << "Please select your file path: " << std::endl;
std::cin >> path;
```

This is the most flexible but also the most annoying solution for the user. Imagine a huge program with hundreds of dependent files. You really don't want to ask the user to insert every location. But this is a perfect solution if you have files that will change often.

**3 - Move the file into your executable location**

When you build your program (compile) VS will place the executables and all files together in an output directory within your project structure (This also depends on your "run configuration").

For me, the path (with default VS and project settings) looks like this.

> C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\Project_Folder\Project\bin\Debug

You can copy your `Random.txt` into this directory or into your project structure and set the flag `copy always` (then it will be copied to the output directory).

HTH